# Query for items with one meta value but without a second one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL table:

| meta_id | item_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 980 | color | white |
| 1001 | 980 | size | large |
| 1002 | 650 | color | white |
| 1003 | 432 | color | white |
| 1004 | 432 | size | large |

What is the query to select the item_id`s who has only "color" and not "size" (in this example: ID: 650)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `SELECT t1.item_id FROM table t1 WHERE t1.meta_key='color' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.meta_key='size' and t2.item_id=t1.item_id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select item_id
from t
where meta_key in ('color', 'size')
group by item_id
having count(*) = 1 and min(meta_key) = 'color';
```

Note:  This assumes that items do not have duplicate keys.

If you wanted the color information, you could also use:

```
select t.*
from t
where meta_key = 'color' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item_id = t.item_id and t2.meta_key = 'size'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT item_id FROM YOUR-TABLE-NAME
WHERE meta_key = "color"
and item_id NOT IN (select item_id from YOUR-TABLE-NAME where item_id = item_id and 
meta_key = "size");
```

Change `YOUR-TABLE-NAME` with the table name.

To simply explain the query:

> it's getting the item_id from the table that has the **meta_key** equals to **color**, and the **same item_id** not in the set of rows that having **meta_key** equals to **size**.